# Selecting sum results from multiple tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am working in the Rails console. I would like to select the SUM of a same named column in two different tables.

Here is my ActiveRecord code:

```
Computer.joins(:services, :repairs)
.select("computers.id, SUM(services.cost) as SCOST, SUM(repairs.cost) as RCOST")
.group("computers.id")
```

This works well and returns the following correct SQL:

```
`SELECT computers.id, SUM(services.cost) as SCOST, SUM(repairs.cost) as RCOST 
FROM "computers" INNER JOIN "services" ON "services"."computer_id" = "computers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "repairs" ON "repairs"."computer_id" = "computers"."id" 
GROUP BY computers.id `
```

But it gives the following result in the Rails console:

```
=> [#<Computer id: 36>, #<Computer id: 32>]
```

Shouldn't I be able to access my SUM values as well? I ran the above SQL query in postgres and it gave the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you should still be able to access the sums.  I think AR only shows the list of returned column names and their values. If you assign that query to `computers`, try `computers.first.SCOST`

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `SCOST'

Comment: i was going to suggest downcasing the aliases but someone already answered that. can you try that?

Comment: I tried simply downcasing the aliases but this did not seem to help from my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rails console uses the [inspect](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L418) method to display the object content. This method doesn't display the values for the custom fields. You will be able to print the value of a custom attribute at the console by explicitly referring to it.

```
Computer.joins(:services, :repairs)
.select("computers.id, SUM(services.cost) as scost, SUM(repairs.cost) as rcost")
.group("computers.id").each do |c|
  puts c.scost
  puts c.rcost
end
```

**Edit**

Example based on comment:

Create a member variable in your controller:

```
@computers = Computer.joins(:services, :repairs)
.select("computers.id, SUM(services.cost) as scost, SUM(repairs.cost) as rcost")
.group("computers.id")
```

Iterate over the variable in your views

```
- @computers.each do |computer| 
  = computer.scost
  = computer.rcost
```

**Edit2**

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get values for computers with missing repairs or services.

```
join_sql = "LEFT OUTER JOIN services ON services.computer_id = computers.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN repairs ON repairs.computer_id = computers.id"
sum_sql  = "SUM(COALESCE(services.cost, 0)) as scost, 
            SUM(COALESCE(repairs.cost, 0)) as rcost"

@computers = Computer.joins(join_sql)
.select("computers.id, #{sum_sql}")
.group("computers.id")
```

Comment: Great work Harish. It prints the results out that I would expect:
`47711.97
4121.95
25131.54
10606.5
=> [#<Computer id: 36>, #<Computer id: 32>]`

Comment: How would I go about accessing these SUM values from an instance variable in my view?

Comment: Thanks Harish. Your solution was fantastic. As a follow up, if there are no rows returned for one of my SUM results, then the whole result set returns 0 results. Eg if we have entries for computer services but not repairs, then 0 rows are returned. I have tried COALESCE(SUM(services.cost),0) as scost  with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: I believe the updated answer does not work correctly. Eg if we have one service record with a value of 5, and then two repair records with the values of 20 each, the rcost SUM I am getting is correct (40) but the scost total is doubled (value of 10). I tested this further by adding another row to repairs (3 rows total), the SUM for repair is correct but the service is now tripled. Meaning the SUM of the table with the least number of rows will be multiplied by the number of rows on the table with the greatest number of rows. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

try as follow,

```
@computer_list = Computer.joins(:services, :repairs).select("computers.id, SUM(services.cost) as SCOST, SUM(repairs.cost) as RCOST").group("computers.id")
@computer_list.last.SCOST
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The result I get is: NoMethodError: undefined method `SCOST' for #<Computer id: 32>